# Banish a popup error message

Tags: centos, notifications

I am connected through VNC to a CentOS 6.4 machine at my workplace. Every five minutes a box pops up that says:

> Authentication is required to set the network proxy used for downloading packages
>
> An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privleges. Authentication as the super user is required to perform this action
>
> Password for root:
>
> Details
>
> Role unknown
>
> Action: org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-network-proxy-configure
>
> Vendor: The PackageKit Project
>
> [Cancel] [Authenticate]

I don't have the root password, so usually I just click it an make it go away but it tends to come back a few minutes later. My local sysadmin has tried to deal with the problem a few times and given up and told me just to keep closing the popup box. That said, its driving me nuts. Is there some way I can make it so I don't have to see the popup, even if the problem isn't itself fixed? Less preferably, is there some very easy thing I can tell the sysadmin to do to actually fix the problem?

Answer (score 16):

I hope you're not one of my users haha! I manage a cluster and this particular warning has been bugging me for a while. I've been trying to figure out a way to fix this programatically on the command line with little success. This error comes from something bundled in [gnome-packagekit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-packagekit/stable/).

I have come across three solutions to this problem

1. disable `/yum/pluginconf.d`

   `[main]
   enabled=0`

   This has not worked for me.
2. Today I found a different answer on the redhat solutions page and I believe that this one works! just add `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to the end of the `/etc/xdg/autostart/gpk-update-icon.desktop` file. I restarted vnc after this and have the popup has not returned.

Unfortunately both solutions so far have required root on the box. I do not believe that the following procedure requires root. But I never tried it since it's done via the GUI:

3. Launch a Terminal Console and type `gnome-session-properties` and then uncheck the *PackageKit Update Applet*.

[image: gnome something screenshot]

sources :

- http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2013/11/fixing-authentication-is-requried-to.html
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/195833

Comment: Using gnome-session-properties didn't require me to enter a password. So the GUI option #3 worked for me, a lowly, non-admin type!

Comment: /etc/xdg/autostart/gpk-update-icon.desktop does not exist - in Centos 7 and rhel 7, the file is /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop but I also get a color managed device auth pop up... :/

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1149893#c13 fixeds the color managed subsequent pop up on rhel 7 for me.

Comment: I love you [echdee](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49304/echdee).

Comment: I think the disable should be /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/refresh-packagekit.conf
but I'm still testing that.

Answer (score 5):

In Centos 7, to remove "*Authentication is required to set the network proxy used for downloading packages*" dialog when you log in - you have to disable autostart of **gnome-software-service**

```
sed -e '$aX-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false' -e '/X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled/d' -i.bak /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop
```

Comment: Or for those of us who want to edit the file manually simply add `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to the end of `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop` and restart `vncserver`

Answer (score 3):

For RHEL6/OEL6 - VNC environments which launch Gnome and see this message ...

Invoking the `gnome-session-properties` app to disable the packagekit update panel results in the modification of the file:

```
~/.config/autostart/gpk-update-icon.desktop
```

aka:

```
$HOME/.config/autostart/gpk-update-icon.desktop
```

As mentioned in earlier posts, it sets:

`X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false`

This file is apparently UTF-8 Unicode text.

Then kill the running copy with `killall -i -u $(whoami) gpk-update-icon`

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL7/OEL7 when you login through and see this message: "Authentication is required to set the network proxy used for downloading software" and stuck in this password input and cannot login.

To resolve this issue: 
Open file `/etc/xdg/autostart/abrt-applet.desktop`

then 
Find line : `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` and change to : `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false`

Restart vnc service and relogin.

Answer (score 0):

*For those travelling here for an answer that don't use remote desktoping, I thought I would share my solution.*

Purging xRDP solved my issue on ubuntu. I was seeing this popup all the time. This was an easy solution for me as remote desktoping isn't a feature I need or use. Also, if I do need it down the road I figure I can get something else.

Code Remove (but leave config files):

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp
```

Code to 100% remove:

```
sudo apt-get purge xrdp
```